# Display Null Elements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table for students (containing a foreign key referencing school) and a table for schools.

I would like display list the Schools in London and total students in each school.

SQL Code is:

```
SELECT
sc.id_school,
sc.name,
count(*) as count
FROM
students as st
INNER JOIN
schools as sc
ON
sc.id_school=st.id_school
WHERE
sc.city='London'
GROUP BY
sc.name
```

The result is:

```
id_school   name    count
2   Gateway     4
3   St Peters   3
```

The result however does not display Schools in London that do not have listed students.

I would want the result to show:

```
id_school   name    count
2   Gateway     4
7   Manchels    0
1   Rowers      0
3   St Peters   3
4   St Johns    0
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `RIGHT` join for schools table, so even if there are no students in london schools they will be returned

```
SELECT
    sc.id_school,
    sc.name,
    count(*) as count
    FROM
    students as st
    RIGHT JOIN
    schools as sc
    ON
    sc.id_school=st.id_school
    WHERE
    sc.city='London'
    GROUP BY
    sc.name
```

Comment: Would it help to state:   `  count(st.name) as count`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to display all the rows 'on the left' even if they have no entry in the column 'count'. Same goes for `RIGHT JOIN`. `OUTER JOIN` displays all combinations.
To display '0' instead of `NULL`:

```
IFNULL(count, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

While @MKhalidJunaid provided the correct answer (I already upvoted), I thought I'd offer another answer that more accurately reflects the data but also should be more performant.

```
SELECT sc.id_school AS School_ID
    ,sc.name AS School_Name
    ,COUNT(st.name) AS Student_Count
FROM schools AS sc
LEFT OUTER JOIN students AS st ON sc.id_school = st.id_school
WHERE sc.city = 'London'
GROUP BY sc.id_school,sc.name
```

By making everything ANSI-compliant (`LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than just `LEFT JOIN`, complete `GROUP BY` statement), as well as making `schools` the driver of the query rather than `students`, you should get the same result set but with some performance gains.

Comment: Thanks PlantTheldea, but this code returns "1" for the ones that are supposed to have "0".

Comment: ah, right. you'd probably need to incorporate the `IFNULL` statement @matthijs used then, which breaks my pure-ANSIness. oh well.

Comment: I used: count(st.name) as count . and it then worked perfect.

Comment: oh sweet! yeah that makes sense, i forgot counting a field in MySQL is handled differently than counting the row (not true of all DBMSs). glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Group by the schoolID

```
SELECT
    sc.id_school,
    sc.name,
    count(*) as count
    FROM
    students as st
    INNER JOIN
    schools as sc
    ON
    sc.id_school=st.id_school
    WHERE
    sc.city='London'
    GROUP BY
    sc.name, sc.id_school;
```